DNS resolution failure for traefik forward auth middleware in kubernetes 1.29.x cluster
I am using traefik 2.10.1 to do a auth middleware, this is the middleware config look like:
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: jwt-token-auth
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
spec:
  forwardAuth:
    address: http://infra-server-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:8081/infra/auth/access_token/verify
    trustForwardHeader: true

When I want to access the kubernetes 1.29.x service in cluster, shows error:
time="2024-07-11T11:56:59Z" level=debug msg="Error calling http://infra-server-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:8081/infra/auth/access_token/verify. Cause: Get \"http://infra-server-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:8081/infra/auth/access_token/verify\": dial tcp: lookup infra-server-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local on 100.100.2.136:53: no such host" middlewareType=ForwardedAuthType middlewareName=reddwarf-pro-jwt-token-auth@kubernetescrd

I have checked the coredns log:
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = 591cf328cccc12bc490481273e738df59329c62c0b729d94e8b61db9961c2fa5f046dd37f1cf888b953814040d180f52594972691cd6ff41be96639138a43908
CoreDNS-1.11.1
linux/amd64, go1.20.7, ae2bbc2

it looks like this kubernetes cluster dns resolve facing some issue. What should I do to fixed this issue? This is the service output:
➜  ~ kubectl --kubeconfig=./.kube/admin.conf get svc -n reddwarf-pro|grep "infra"
infra-server-service        ClusterIP   10.100.155.34    <none>        8081/TCP                       7d20h

this is the nslookup command result:
root@y-websocket-service-9654986bc-cf65m:/home/node/app# nslookup cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

*** Can't find cluster.local: No answer

root@y-websocket-service-9654986bc-cf65m:/home/node/app# nslookup svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

*** Can't find svc.cluster.local: No answer

this is the pod /etc/resolve.conf:
root@y-websocket-service-9654986bc-cf65m:/home/node/app# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5

Finnally found from the traefik pod could not work:
/ $ nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     100.100.2.136
Address:    100.100.2.136:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

other pod works fine.
